# Script For sending many HTTP request at a time for checking server load

Tags: apache, http

I want check my AWS autoscling is working fine when the CPU utilization is greater then 80%.So i want a script for send many http resuest to my AWS server for testing.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several tools to accomplish this task, two of them are

[ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html), a command line tool build into Apache:

> ab is a tool for benchmarking your Apache Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) server. It is designed to give you an impression of how your current Apache installation performs. This especially shows you how many requests per second your Apache installation is capable of serving.

[jMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org), a graphical testing tool written in Java:

> The Apache JMeter™ application is open source software, a 100% pure Java application designed to load test functional behavior and measure performance. It was originally designed for testing Web Applications but has since expanded to other test functions.

Handle them with care, as they really do what you are requesting. I've managed to brute force my test server until it collapsed with ab quite easy...

Comment: Can i use any script to send many request at a time(1000 http requests) to my aws server to test server Load and CPu utilization.?